How to store characters other than english in C language char data type?
I want to store punjabi language character in char data type, how can I do it?
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ch = 'ਜ';
    printf("%c", ch);

    return 0;
}

the above line prints wrong value after warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar], how can I fix this?

yes, thanks for the quick help

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf
i believe this will contain an answer to your question.
